# Choosing the right term: Professional vs Premium

Tags: terminology

I'm having to choose a marketing name for a commercial version of a product. I have to decide if use the term "Professional" or "Premium".

In terms of User Experience, can someone help me to spot the difference between the two terms? What do they make users think of?

Comment: a better fit on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions) perhaps?

Comment: IMO, communication and terminology should be aspects of a good user experience. This question is about the way words can trigger user's actions.

Comment: "Trigger user's actions", rather the framing of a product leading to a purchase or not. This is not a question regarding UX, it's a question regarding marketing and market labeling.

Comment: "user's action" can refer not only to "making purchases", but includes a much broader set of events, like launching a search, or saving a document. All these events can be labeled with texts, so here we are with UX... by the way, according to your position, is there a stack exchange for this?

Comment: it's not interaction design and it's not information design. Something like "Should I arrange the table presenting the features of my app this way" would be a question regarding information design, and therefore a UX oriented. The choice between calling a commercial product "Premium" or "Professional" is not UX, it's conversion, but not UX. It's solely a marketing decision. Something a UX professional may come across, sure, do work with an e-commerce site and you will. But it's no more UX oriented then "how do I install Balsamiq Mockups on Linux", something a designer may also come across.

Comment: And no, there's no established site for Marketing. Digital Marketing has 60+ votes on Area 51, but hasn't had its break so far.

Comment: Spending so many words about things like "what is and what isn't", doesn't help. Even if I could agree with some of your points, your examination is largely arbitrary. Someone below has been more helpful. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, perhaps obviously, professional suggests more suited to a working environment than a home environment, and premium suggests superior, perhaps an enhanced or more luxury alternative.

Rather than limiting yourself to 'Professional' or 'Premium', you could come up with a word that expresses the advantage of the commercial version.

e.g. speedy, unlimited, unbreakable, secure, supported, etc.

I'd use professional if you want to sell to commercial users and have the other version for home users, and premium if you can't think of a single more suitable word.